# What does "так и есть" and "ну что ж" mean?

Tags: узус

What does ***"так и есть"*** and ***"ну что ж"*** mean, are these idioms?

How are they used in sentences?

Answer (score 10):

`Так и есть` means **"that's right," "that's true."** It's used to agree with someone:

> Жизнь не проста. - **Так и есть** (= действительно, и правда, верно, согласен/согласна).

In English it's not always necessary to use a phrase like "that's right." See the example below:

> Ужасно? - Да, **так и есть.** (Awful? - **Yes, it is.**)

`Так и есть` can be used for a different reason too:

> **Если так и есть**, то это плохо. (**if it's really so**, it's bad.)

In this case, `так и есть` means "если это так."

`Ну что ж` means **"well"** (used as an interjection):

> Ну что ж, давайте начнём. (Well, let's start.)

Comment: Depending on context and intonation "ну что ж" can be more like "oh, well...", rather than just "well,...".

Answer (score 1):

**ТАК И ЕСТЬ (разговорная частица)**

1)  **Подтверждение сказанного:** Я с ним согласен, всё так и есть. Возможно, это так и есть.

2) **Соответствие (в сложном предложении)**: Как он сказал, так и есть. Если всё так и есть, то хорошо.

2) **Соответствие тому, что ожидалось или предполагалось**: Подергал  дверь ― так и есть, заперта! Ну, так и есть. Всё, как я и предполагала.

**НУ ЧТО Ж (НУ ЧТО ЖЕ) (разговорная частица)**

НУ обозначает побуждение к действию, ЧТО – вопросительное слово,  ЖЕ (Ж) – усилительная частица.

1) **Согласие, принятое решение**: Ну что ж, пойдемте. Ну что ж, это можно.

2) **Вывод, оценка**: Ну что ж, насильно мил не будешь. Ну что ж, этого следовало ожидать. Ну что ж, возможно, он прав.

3) **Вопрос о дальнейших действиях:** Ну что ж, пойдем или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Also «так и есть» can mean just «yes».

*— Ты же собирался в кафе!* (I thought you were going to the cafe)
*— Так и есть. Пойду через минуту.* (Yes. I'm going there in a minute.)

Answer (score 0):

"так и есть" = verily so

"ну что ж" may, depending on the context, be translated either "be it as it may" or as "oh, whatever..."